FastEndPoints swagger endpoint grouping name lower case issue
I'm using fastendpoints for my latest project. In designing endpoints I face following issue.

just note that simple case in substring "Roles".
Here is how I configure the endpoint

Does anyone have an idea of how to fix this lowercase issue? Thanks in advance.

you have two options.
1.) the default behavior is to convert the group/tag names to title case. which can be changed like so:
.SwaggerDocument(o => o.TagCase = TagCase.None);

2.) or you can specify per endpoint what the actual tag/group should be for that endpoint. which will override the auto detected route segment based tag value:
public override void Configure()
{
    Get("OperationalRoles/{ClientId}");
    Description(x => x.AutoTagOverride("Operational Roles"));
}

alternatively you can turn off the route/path segment based auto tagging and specify what tag the endpoint belongs to per endpoint like so:
.SwaggerDocument(o => o.AutoTagPathSegmentIndex = 0);

public override void Configure()
{
    Description(x => x.WithTags("Operational Roles"));
}

